# PowerBI : Creating Real time report without using Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power BI. I have a requirement where I need to create a Real-time Report.

My data is coming from Event Hub but we don't want to use Azure Stream Analytics.

So how can we do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? People are more included to help if you demonstrate some effort and research.

Comment: I am in information gathering phase,i did some RnD and found that we can use Azure Stream Analytics for this.But in my organization they don't want to use this as they tell it is costly.So I am not sure how can we Push the data from Event hub to PowerBi?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other opportunities like pubnub or create a small scheduled console application/script (and use the Power BI API).

More information for creating such an application can be found here: https://www.sqlshack.com/real-time-streaming-in-power-bi/

Comment: Thanks Rick.I have below question : I was checking : [SamplePUSHDataset](https://thstechbit.blogspot.com/2018/01/sample-app-to-push-data-to-power-bi.html)  this is also a form of PUSH data right?So for this Do we need to Create a PUSH URL on Power BI Service,as in code it is like string powerBIUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg" ?2:we say that we have limitation of 200,000 row in PUSH so this means that each time API run it can bring Max of 200,000 rows?3:Suppose I want to run the AI like every 3 mins Can I do it..Like what can be frequency of running the API in case of PUSH daatset

Comment: Yes you have to create an API directly in PowerBI. In your workspace go to CREATE+ -> Streaming Dataset and define all your JSON values, that the power BI service can get. I do not know exactly the limitations and frequency (I think 200.000 rows limit is only for caching if you activate historical data analsys) but you should not get any problems with your approach. Try it out then you will find the answer :)

Comment: Rick..Creating API from PowerBi will either have Hybrid (Push and Streaming) or just streaming. How can I have just Push?

Comment: I do not get your issue now? You have stated you want a real-time report? The created URL should be fine with PUSH! If you do not care about real time you can also define your data source manually and depend your power bi report on direct query an set the refreshment as you want..

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a demo report with similar requirement. To demonstrate how things will work, we created a real-time report that shows weather information like wind speed, temperature, etc live data.

To eliminate azure from the picture, we had to create a c# console application, which runs in the background and pushes the data in the database at a specified interval of time (in our case every 15 seconds) with a timestamp.

Comment: So for Push ,Did you register your app?something like https://thstechbit.blogspot.com/2018/01/sample-app-to-push-data-to-power-bi.html  .I am confused between pushing after registering the app and pushing the data after we declare the json on powerBi Service when we create dataset through API.What is the difference between two?